# Where can I find the version of the song "Never Knew Love Like This Before" that is played in the movie "I Give It a Year"?

Tags: pop

"Never Knew Like This Before" is a song that was originally sung by Stephanie Mills.

Jessie Ware sang this song in the opening scene of the movie "I Give It a Year". However, I cannot find the specific version of this song that is used in this movie. Does anyone know where I can find it?

The version used in the movie "I Give It a Year" by Jessie Ware: https://www5.putlockerhd.io/film/i-give-it-a-year-mfj/watching.html?ep=1

The original version by Stephanie Mills:

The cover version by Jessie Ware (this is not the version that is used in the movie "I Give It a Year"):

Comment: Link to Stephanie Mills original is broken.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv7ABbl_86E Did you actually try to Google "Jessie Ware" Never Knew Love Like This Before ?